# Multirow is not working

Tags: tables, multirow, sharelatex

I am trying to create a table listing advantages and disadvantages of diferent providers , but I can't make the `\multirow` command readable. Where should I include it? I got this table code from someone who posted here. I am still new to latex so I am trying to understand why It is not reading and where I should post it. Here is te code I am using.

```
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  \usepackage[toc]{glossaries}
  \usepackage{enumitem}
  \usepackage{graphicx}
  \usepackage{booktabs}
  \usepackage{float}
  \usepackage{multirow}
  \usepackage{tabu}

  \usepackage{array}

\newcommand*{\arraycolor}[1]{\protect\leavevmode\color{#1}}
\newcolumntype{A}{>{\columncolor{blue!50!white}}c}
\newcolumntype{B}{>{\columncolor{green!50!white}}c}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\columncolor{FireBrick!50}}c}
\newcolumntype{D}{>{\columncolor{Gray!42}}c}

\begin{table} [H]

\begin{center}
\sffamily
\arrayrulecolor{white}
\arrayrulewidth=1pt
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\rowcolors[\hline]{3}{.!50!White}{}
\begin{tabular}{D|B|C}
  %\multicolumn{4}{D}{\bfseries Example table}\\
\rowcolor{.!50!Black}
\arraycolor{White}\bfseries Solution &
\arraycolor{White}\bfseries Advantages &
\arraycolor{White}\bfseries Disadvantages \\
\multirow{3}{*}{Provider A} & B & C \\
Provider B & B & F \\
Provider C & C & G \\
Provider D & D & H \\
Provider E & D & H \\
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Please post with packages you have used@G. Doe

Comment: @BikiTeron I am using the `\multirow` package

Comment: You need the free line under your original one. So if you have this you need a `\multirow{3}{*}{Provider A} & B & C\\ & &\\ & &`.

Comment: @TeXnician it does not create a multirow, it creates new rows and does not show the Provider A name.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick and dirty workaround. You need to define all rows you want it to span in advance (that's required in any case).

[image: table with multirow]

```
\documentclass{article}
 \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  \usepackage[toc]{glossaries}
  \usepackage{enumitem}
  \usepackage{graphicx}
  \usepackage{booktabs}
  \usepackage{float}
  \usepackage{multirow}
  \usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage[table,dvipsnames,svgnames]{xcolor}
  \usepackage{array}

\newcommand*{\arraycolor}[1]{\protect\leavevmode\color{#1}}
\newcolumntype{A}{>{\columncolor{blue!50!white}}c}
\newcolumntype{B}{>{\columncolor{green!50!white}}c}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\columncolor{FireBrick!50}}c}
\newcolumntype{D}{>{\columncolor{Gray!42}}c}

\begin{document}
\begin{table} [H]

\begin{center}
\sffamily
\arrayrulecolor{white}
\arrayrulewidth=1pt
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\rowcolors[\hline]{3}{.!50!White}{}
\begin{tabular}{D|B|C}
  %\multicolumn{4}{D}{\bfseries Example table}\\
\rowcolor{.!50!Black}
\arraycolor{White}\bfseries Solution &
\arraycolor{White}\bfseries Advantages &
\arraycolor{White}\bfseries Disadvantages \\
 & B & C \\
& &\\
\multirow{-3}{*}{Provider A}& &\\
Provider B & B & F \\
Provider C & C & G \\
Provider D & D & H \\
Provider E & D & H \\
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I was wondering if there is a way to expand the provider A row, instead of adding new rows with new colors?

Comment: @G.Doe multirow is just intended to make a cell span more than one row. There are posts on this site describing the problems of multirow in environments with multiple colors. And concerning the new rows: multirow does only make sense, if you have more than one row.

Comment: I wante to have more than one row but with the same color of provider A, since I wanted to show all the extra rows belongs to it. But thanks. i will try to think another way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

It is a classical problem with `\multirow` in coloured tables. The trick is to place the `\multirow` command in the last ‘multirowed’ cell, with a negative argument:

```
\documentclass{article}
 \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  \usepackage[toc]{glossaries}
  \usepackage{enumitem}
  \usepackage{graphicx}
  \usepackage{booktabs}
  \usepackage{float}
  \usepackage{multirow}
  \usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage[table, svgnames]{xcolor}

\usepackage{array}

\newcommand*{\arraycolor}[1]{\protect\leavevmode\color{#1}}
\newcolumntype{A}{>{\columncolor{blue!50!white}}c}
\newcolumntype{B}{>{\columncolor{green!50!white}}c}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\columncolor{FireBrick!50}}c}
\newcolumntype{D}{>{\columncolor{Gray!42}}c}

\begin{document}

\begin{table} [H]

  \begin{center}
    \sffamily
    \arrayrulecolor{white}
    \arrayrulewidth=1pt
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
    \rowcolors[\hline]{3}{.!50!White}{}
    \begin{tabular}{D|B|C}
      %\multicolumn{4}{D}{\bfseries Example table}\\
      \rowcolor{.!50!Black}
      \arraycolor{White}\bfseries Solution &
      \arraycolor{White}\bfseries Advantages &
      \arraycolor{White}\bfseries Disadvantages \\
                                             & B & C \\
                                             & & \\
      \multirow{-3}{*}{Provider A} & & \\
      Provider B & B & F \\
      Provider C & C & G \\
      Provider D & D & H \\
      Provider E & D & H \\
    \end{tabular}
  \end{center}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I did that too in my answer, but that's unfortunately not satisfying for the OP (see comments on my answer).

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit hard to understand, but judging by your comment on one of the other answers, it seems like this is what you're after. I used `\cellcolor` to override the color setting defined by `\rowcolors`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[table, svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{array}
\newcommand*{\arraycolor}[1]{\protect\leavevmode\color{#1}}
\newcolumntype{A}{>{\columncolor{blue!50!white}}c}
\newcolumntype{B}{>{\columncolor{green!50!white}}c}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\columncolor{FireBrick!50}}c}
\newcolumntype{D}{>{\columncolor{Gray!42}}c}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[H]

\centering
    \sffamily
    \arrayrulecolor{white}
    \arrayrulewidth=1pt
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
    \rowcolors[\hline]{3}{.!50!White}{}
    \begin{tabular}{D|B|C}
      %\multicolumn{4}{D}{\bfseries Example table}\\
      \rowcolor{.!50!Black}
      \arraycolor{White}\bfseries Solution &
      \arraycolor{White}\bfseries Advantages &
      \arraycolor{White}\bfseries Disadvantages \\
      Provider A & B & C \\
\cellcolor{Gray!42}& \cellcolor{green!50!white} & \cellcolor{FireBrick!50}\\
&&\\
      Provider B & B & F \\
      Provider C & C & G \\
      Provider D & D & H \\
      Provider E & D & H \\
    \end{tabular}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```